# What CMS integrations are available for CiviCRM?

Tags: cms-integration

Many CRM platforms offer integrations with a CMS, where they can do things like the following:

1. Provide demographic groups to the CMS to use in personalization
2. Accept form posts from the CMS for lead entry
3. Identify CRM users on the website and track their website activities in the CRM

To what extent does CiviCRM have integrations like this for any CMS?

I've searched quite a bit, but the CMS integrations I see for CiviCRM are more of the "make CiviCRM run *inside* a particular CMS." Like, how to make CiviCRM run inside Drupal. (Or Joomla, or WordPress...)

If my CMS-powered website is separate from CiviCRM, what *pre-built* options does it have to integrate with any CMS?

I know it has an extensive API, and can all of this stuff can be custom-built, but are there are packages/modules/add-ons that bridge the gap between CMS X and CiviCRM in the ways I have described?

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM has a complete set of [APIs](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/general/) that you can use for such purpose, but you would have to custom-develop the part that sits within this other CMS. So for example you can use (Contact, Get) with the email address of the logged-in user in the CMS to achieve function 1 in your list, or (Contact, create) to create leads in CiviCRM from a website form and achieve function 2 in your list, or (Activity, create) to track website activities in the CRM and achieve function 3 in your list.